# Multi class prediction probability in Graphlab / Turi

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda, graphlab

I am working on multiclass problem (num_class=100). I have created a classification model in graphlab/Turi

```
  import graphlab as gl
  model= gl.boosted_trees_classifier.create(tr_data, target='species',max_depth=4, max_iterations=500)
```

Then predicted the probabilities of test set

```
  model.classify(te_data)
```

Its producing majority class probabilities. How can I modify the model to get probabilities of all 100 classes of target.
Thanks in anticipation.